# Is G isomorphic to a Subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb C)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

I'm stuck on a question on a past exam paper that asks if a group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup
$GL(2,\mathbb C)$. We are given the character table for $G$ which I've attached below. It's the last part of a question so I've already worked out that $G$ is simple and not soluable, but I'm not really sure where to start with this. I can't find anything in my notes that will help me.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

The question is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzvtK.png), its Q2 part f.

Comment: Hint: The group has a faithful character of degree $2$.

Comment: Also, it is not simple because some of the characters have nontrivial kernels. IIn fact there is a normal subgroup $N$ of order $2$ with simple quotient $G/N$.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! And I see where I went wrong in thinking it was simple now.